# How to get id from array database

Tags: html, laravel

I have a problem when show my array, like below

```html
<table>
...prev code
@foreach($obat as $o)
...prev code

 <input type="text" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $obat[0]->kode_obat}}">

@endforeach
</table>
```

i need the `$obat[0]->kode_obat` array to be looping, so i don't have to change the value array (`[0]`)

I want it to show like this

```
# | kode_obat|nama_obat|...ect
1 | OB0001   |lalal    |...
1 | OB0002   |KKKKK    |...
```

This is the array

```
Collection {#476 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#482 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"kode_obat": "OB001"
      +"nama_obat": "made obat`"
      +"harga_obat": "50000"
      +"stok": "5"
    }
    1 => {#477 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"kode_obat": "OB002"
      +"nama_obat": "made ee"
      +"harga_obat": "4500"
      +"stok": "sadasd"
    }
    2 => {#201 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: try with  `$o->code` instead `$obat[0]->code`

Comment: foreach ($array as $key => $value)

Comment: please provide us array structure and output that you want

Comment: Hi I've update my Question, please check again

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `[0]` if you are using `foreach` loop and use `$o` instead of `$obat` because,on each iteration the foreach loop assign array element to `$o`.

```
<table>
 @foreach($obat as $o)

 <input type="text" name="nama_obat" value="{{($o->kode_obat)}}">

 @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blade Looping works exactly like foreach loop of php so you have to do it like this.

```
<table>
  ...prev code
     @foreach($obat as $o)
  ...prev code

       <input type="text" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat}}">

     @endforeach
</table>
```

If you want other columns from the same table you can do like this.

```
<input type="text" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->nama_obat}}">
```